# How can I intercept a single XHR/fetch request, without affecting requests afterwards?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, race-condition

I am building a React/Typescript app, running completely client-side in browser. In `componentDidMount()`, I make a fetch request which I intercept successfully, to change the URL, and then make that request.

For reference, the API object is also from a third party library, loaded in via an HTML script tag, so I don't have access to the inner workings of the object. That's why I'm attempting to intercept the call instead to point the URL at a different endpoint.

```
async function makeRequest() {
  let originalFetch = redefineFetch();
  let data;
  try {
    data = await API.fetchData();
    
  } catch (error) {
    resetFetch(originalFetch);
    return;
  }
  resetFetch(originalFetch);
  return data;
}

const redefineFetch = () => {
  const { fetch: originalFetch } = window;
  let originalWindowFetch = window.fetch;
  window.fetch = async (...args) => {
    let [resource, config] = args;
    resource = NEW_URL;
    const response = await originalFetch(resource, config);
    return response;
  };
  return originalWindowFetch;
};

const resetFetch = (
  originalFetch: ((input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined) => Promise<Response>) &
    ((input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined) => Promise<Response>)
) => {
  console.log("Resetting fetch");
  window.fetch = originalFetch;
};
```

**How I'm currently doing it:**

I copied how it was done in this blog post. https://blog.logrocket.com/intercepting-javascript-fetch-api-requests-responses/.

As you can see, `makeRequest()` calls `redefineFetch()`, which redefines `window.fetch` to point to the NEW_URL instead.

`redefineFetch()` returns the original implementation of fetch as `originalFetch`.
After making the request, I call `resetFetch()` and pass `originalFetch`.
I then set `window.fetch = originalFetch`.

**What I think is the issue**

Every request including and after `API.fetchData()` now point to the NEW_URL.
These requests are out of my control in timing as they are made by 3rd party portions of my code.

I think I'm either not setting window.fetch back to its original value correctly, OR there's a race condition in which these mistakenly intercepted requests are being made before `resetFetch()` is called.

**My Questions**

How can I redefine fetch only for the `API.fetchData()` call without risking affecting any other calls made in my app?

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I decided to do it was to just use an if statement in `makeRequest()` to check if the url for the request matches the one I want to intercept, then only modifying it if it matches. Otherwise I leave it the same. It's not a perfect solution as you could have situations where you have the same request multiple times, but for my use case it works.